# How Can I extend a React functional Component Prop Type?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-props

I have a react functional component which works perfectly and I'm using typescript for this component.
I want to extend it a little so I could use it other places too, the challenge is I used a type for a prop which I don't want to change , but to extend it ,
here is the component:

```
const CargoCard = (props: CargoGetListResultModel) => {
  ** Some Code here **
}
```

Can anyone please help me how can I extend prop types?
for example I want to add two new props like

```
{isExtended: boolean; extendedData: {id: number, title: string}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Intersection Types

```
type ExtendedType = CargoGetListResultModel & {isExtended: boolean; extendedData: {id: number, title: string}};

// inline:

const CargoCard = (props: CargoGetListResultModel & {isExtended: boolean; extendedData: {id: number, title: string}}) => {
  // ** Some Code here **
}
```

Check out https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html for more examples.